# Default avatar NOT changing in IPBoard

Tags: image, avatar, gravatar, forums, ipb

Hey I need help changing the default avatar in IPBoard,
I have done almost everything I could think of,
I have Disabled Gravatars and replaced the default_large.png and default_thumb.png BUT the avatar is STILL the default that comes with IPB... upon further inspection, ONLY default_thumb.png has changed.. even though I have replaced default_large.png with my own, It still displays as the IPB default one when going directly to it... can someone plz help?

http://craft101.info/forums/public/style_images/master/profile/default_large.png
http://craft101.info/forums/public/style_images/master/profile/default_thumb.png

Comment: Nevermind.. I have found a temp workaround that I like, I replaced the path with "'http://minotar.net/avatar/' . $member['members_display_name'];"

Comment: This leads me to another question.. is there a way I could make it get the data from a custom field instead of the display name? like for example, "'http://minotar.net/avatar/' . $fields['field11'];" (their minecraft name, field, in my database, currently), but alas that example did not work? to be clear, I am in "ipsMember.php"